# How to install sublime text 3, which already detach from the terminal from starting in centos7

Tags: linux, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have install the sublime 3 in centos7. This sublime installation is depended on the terminal which started the sublime. If I close the terminal or press Ctrl+c, Then sublime will be kill, other thing one terminal tab is dedicated to sublime, So please help how to make sublime independent from sublime 3.

For installation of sublime I followed the steps from [this link](http://www.tecmint.com/install-sublime-text-editor-in-linux/)

```
# cd ~
# wget http://c758482.r82.cf2.rackcdn.com/Sublime\ Text\ 2.0.2\ x64.tar.bz2
# tar vxjf Sublime\ Text\ 2.0.2\ x64.tar.bz2

# sudo mv Sublime\ Text\ 2 /opt/
```

For creating the symbolic name

```
# sudo ln -s /opt/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text /usr/bin/sublime
```

**I am looking for permanent solution.....**

Comment: Make an executable shell script that runs sublime as a background process.

Answer (score 1):

Background the process by using an &.

```
/usr/bin/sublime &
```

You calso use ctrl-z to stop the process then use bg.

Answer (score 0):

Before I start, I would **strongly** urge you to use [Sublime Text 3](http://sublimetext.com/3) instead. It has many many improvements over ST2, which is not being developed any more, so no bugs will be fixed or new features added. While ST3 is technically still a "beta", it is perfectly stable and completely capable of production work - in fact, in my experience, it is *more* stable than ST2, which is not threaded and can easily crash if a plugin dies. The [ST3 API](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html) has vastly improved, but in some backwards-incompatible ways, so many new (and existing) [plugins](https://packagecontrol.io) only support ST3, with ST2 support either being dropped entirely, or not developed any more. I've been using ST3 almost exclusively for over 2 years now, and wouldn't dream of going back.

---

You can easily create an icon on your desktop to start Sublime without involving Terminal at all. I'm not a CentOS user, but apparently the default desktop environment is Gnome 3, so the steps to creating an application shortcut are essentially the same as for Ubuntu. I [answered](https://askubuntu.com/a/397387/169120) a similar question on Ask Ubuntu, but I'll summarize it here.

If you decide to use ST3 instead, first download the tarball, unzip it, then move it to `/opt/sublime_text`:

```
sudo mv sublime_text_3 /opt/sublime_text
```

Next, move `/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text.desktop` to `/usr/share/applications`. Then, create a symlink to it on your desktop:

```
ln -s /usr/share/applications/sublime_text.desktop "~/Desktop/Sublime Text 3.desktop"
```

Finally, you'll need to fix your `/usr/bin/sublime` symlink to point to ST3:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/sublime
sudo ln -s /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text /usr/bin/sublime
```

And you're all set. Simply double-click on the `Sublime Text 3` icon on your desktop, and it will start.

---

If you insist on using ST2, you'll need to create the `.desktop` file yourself, then move it to `/usr/share/applications`. Open a blank file in Sublime and add the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Sublime Text 2
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Sophisticated text editor for code, markup and prose
Exec=/opt/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text %F
Terminal=false
MimeType=text/plain;
Icon=sublime-text
Categories=TextEditor;Development;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=Window;Document;

[Desktop Action Window]
Name=New Window
Exec=/opt/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text -n
OnlyShowIn=Unity;

[Desktop Action Document]
Name=New File
Exec=/opt/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text --command new_file
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

Save the file someplace as `sublime_text_2.desktop`. Then, `sudo mv` it to `/usr/share/applications`, then create a symlink to your `~/Desktop` as described above.